# Что представляет собой cout?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, поток-ввода

`cout` не ключевое слово. Он подключается через библиотеку `iostream` и сам редактор vs говорит что это функция.
Вопрос: почему у него (к `cin` тоже относится) синтаксис не как у нормальных С++ функций ( `cout("привет")` ) и при чем тут побитовый сдвиг (<<>>)?

Comment: А почему вы вообще подумали о *функциях*? `cout` - это переменная, а не функция.

Answer (score 7):

Вкратце - потому что это *объект* класса `ostream`, а в этом классе переопределен оператор `<<`, который при работе с объектом данного класса действует не как оператор сдвига, а как вызов функции с именем `operator<<`, которая осуществляет вывод в поток.

Более полно - рекомендую почитать материалы о потоках ввода-вывода в C++ и переопределении операторов.

Точно так же `cin` - предопределенный объект класса `istream`.

P.S. для педантов - да, я знаю, что эти названия типов - на самом деле инстанцирования `basic_istream/basic_ostream` :)